# deployment errors in code due to constructor arguments

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, javascript, hardhat, error

here is the contarct I am trying to deploy:

```
// Raffle

// Enter the lottery (paying some amount)
// Pick a random Winner (verifiably random)
// Winner to be selected every x-minutes -> completely automated

// Chainlink Oracle -> Randomness, Automated Execution (Chainlink Keepers)

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/KeeperCompatibleInterface.sol";

error Raffle__NotEnoughETHEntered();
error Raffle__TransferFailed();
error Raffle__NotOpen();
error Raffle_UpkeepNotNeeded(uint256 currentBalance, uint256 numPlayers, uint256 raffleState);

/**
* @title A sample contract
* @author Anooj Patnaik
* @notice This Contract is for creating an untamperable decentralised smart contract
* @dev This implements Chainlink VRF v2 and Chainlink Keepers
*/

contract Raffle is VRFConsumerBaseV2, KeeperCompatibleInterface {
   /* Type declarations */
   enum RaffleState {
       OPEN,
       CALCULATING
   } // UINT256 0 = open, 1 = closed

   /* State Variables */
   uint256 private immutable i_entranceFee;
   address payable[] private s_players;
   VRFCoordinatorV2Interface private immutable i_vrfCoordinator;
   bytes32 private immutable i_gasLane;
   uint64 private immutable i_subscriptionId;
   uint16 private constant REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS = 3;
   uint16 private immutable i_callbackGasLimit;
   uint32 private constant NUM_WORDS = 1;

   // Lottery Variables
   address private s_recentWinner;
   RaffleState private s_raffleState; //to pending, open, closed, calculating
   uint256 private s_lastTimeStamp;
   uint256 private immutable i_interval;

   /* Events */
   event RaffleEnter(address indexed player);
   event RequestedRaffleWinner(uint256 indexed requestId);
   event WinnerPicked(address indexed winner);

   constructor(
       address vrfCoordinatorV2, // contract
       uint256 entranceFee,
       bytes32 gasLane,
       uint64 subscriptionId,
       uint16 callbackGasLimit,
       uint256 interval
   ) VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinatorV2) {
       i_vrfCoordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinatorV2);
       i_entranceFee = entranceFee;
       i_gasLane = gasLane;
       i_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
       i_callbackGasLimit = callbackGasLimit;
       s_raffleState = RaffleState.OPEN;
       s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
       i_interval = interval;
   }

   /* Functions */
   function enterRaffle() public payable {
       // require msg.value > i_entranceFee
       if (msg.value < i_entranceFee) {
           revert Raffle__NotEnoughETHEntered();
       }
       if (s_raffleState != RaffleState.OPEN) {
           revert Raffle__NotOpen();
       }
       s_players.push(payable(msg.sender));
       // Events: an event is when we update a dynamic array or a mapping
       // Named events with the function name reversed
       emit RaffleEnter(msg.sender);
   }

   /**
    * @dev THis is the function that the Chainlink Keeper nodes call
    * they look for the upkeepNeeded to return true
    * following should be true in order to return true:
    * 1. our time interval should have passed
    * 2. The lottery should have atleast 1 player and must have some ETH
    * 3. Our subscription should be funded with LINK
    * 4. The lottery should be in open state
    */

   function checkUpkeep(
       bytes memory /*checkData*/
   ) public override returns (bool upKeepNeeded, bytes memory /*performData*/) {
       bool isOpen = (RaffleState.OPEN == s_raffleState);
       bool timePassed = ((block.timestamp - s_lastTimeStamp) > i_interval);
       bool hasPlayers = (s_players.length > 0);
       bool hasBalance = address(this).balance > 0;
       upKeepNeeded = (isOpen && timePassed && hasPlayers && hasBalance);
       // (block.timestamp - last block timestamp) > interval
   }

   function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /*performData*/) external override {
       // Request random Number
       // once we get it, do something with it
       // 2 transaction process
       (bool upkeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("");
       if (!upkeepNeeded) {
           revert Raffle_UpkeepNotNeeded(
               address(this).balance,
               s_players.length,
               uint256(s_raffleState)
           );
       }
       s_raffleState = RaffleState.CALCULATING;
       uint256 requestId = i_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
           i_gasLane, // gaslane
           i_subscriptionId,
           i_callbackGasLimit,
           REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS,
           NUM_WORDS
       );
       emit RequestedRaffleWinner(requestId);
   }

   function fulfillRandomWords(
       uint256 /*requestId*/,
       uint256[] memory randomWords
   ) internal override {
       uint256 indexOfWinner = randomWords[0] % s_players.length;
       address payable recentWinner = s_players[indexOfWinner];
       s_recentWinner = recentWinner;
       s_raffleState = RaffleState.OPEN;
       s_players = new address payable[](0);
       s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
       (bool success, ) = recentWinner.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
       if (!success) {
           revert Raffle__TransferFailed();
       }
       emit WinnerPicked(recentWinner);
   }

   /* View / Pure functions */
   function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {
       return i_entranceFee;
   }

   function getPlayer(uint256 index) public view returns (address) {
       return s_players[index];
   }

   function getRecentWinner() public view returns (address) {
       return s_recentWinner;
   }

   function getRaffleState() public view returns (RaffleState) {
       return s_raffleState;
   }

   function getNumWords() public pure returns (uint256) {
       return NUM_WORDS;
   }

   function getNumberOfPlayers() public view returns (uint256) {
       return s_players.length;
   }

   function getLatestTimeStamp() public view returns (uint256) {
       return s_lastTimeStamp;
   }

   function getRequestConfirmations() public pure returns (uint256) {
       return REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS;
   }

   function getInterval() public view returns (uint256) {
       return i_interval;
   }
}
```

here is the deployment script from which I am getting errors:

```
const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const {
    networkConfig,
    developmentChains,
    VERIFICATION_BLOCK_CONFIRMATIONS,
} = require("../helper-hardhat-config")
const { verify } = require("../utils/verify")

const FUND_AMOUNT = ethers.utils.parseEther("1") // 1 Ether, or 1e18 (10^18) Wei

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const chainId = network.config.chainId
    let vrfCoordinatorV2Address, subscriptionId, vrfCoordinatorV2Mock

    if (chainId == 31337) {
        // create VRFV2 Subscription
        vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.address
        const transactionResponse = await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription()
        const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait()
        subscriptionId = transactionReceipt.events[0].args.subId
        // Fund the subscription
        // Our mock makes it so we don't actually have to worry about sending fund
        await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fundSubscription(subscriptionId, FUND_AMOUNT)
    } else {
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = networkConfig[chainId]["vrfCoordinatorV2"]
        subscriptionId = networkConfig[chainId]["subscriptionId"]
    }
    const waitBlockConfirmations = developmentChains.includes(network.name)
        ? 1
        : VERIFICATION_BLOCK_CONFIRMATIONS

    log("----------------------------------------------------")
    const args = [
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address,
        networkConfig[chainId]["raffleEntranceFee"],
        networkConfig[chainId]["gasLane"],
        subscriptionId,
        networkConfig[chainId]["callbackGasLimit"],
        networkConfig[chainId]["keepersUpdateInterval"],
    ]
    const raffle = await deploy("Raffle", {
        from: deployer,
        args: args,
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: waitBlockConfirmations,
    })

    // Ensure the Raffle contract is a valid consumer of the VRFCoordinatorV2Mock contract.
    if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
        const vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")
        await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.addConsumer(subscriptionId, raffle.address)
    }

    // Verify the deployment
    if (!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
        log("Verifying...")
        await verify(raffle.address, arguments)
    }

    log("Enter lottery with command:")
    const networkName = network.name == "hardhat" ? "localhost" : network.name
    log(`yarn hardhat run scripts/enterRaffle.js --network ${networkName}`)
    log("----------------------------------------------------")
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "raffle"]
```

the error that I am getting: **An unexpected error occurred:

Error: ERROR processing /home/anooj-patnaik/hardhat-raffle-lottery/deploy/01-deploy-raffle.js:
Error: value out-of-bounds (argument="callbackGasLimit", value="5000000", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.7.0)**

can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument `callbackGasLimit` in the constructor is of type `uint16`. The maximum value it can be is `2**16 - 1 = 65535`.

However you're passing a value of `5000000`, which raises the error "Error: value out-of-bounds".

Probably you need to raise the number of bits for the variable, `uint32` should be enough.

Comment: thank you! that did the job